# ListView has stopped

Tags: java, android, listview, android-arrayadapter, layout-inflater

I'm trying to create a listview with images, but when I launch my app android says unfortunatelly it has stopped. I followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h1yTifTO-ss).

Where is mistake?

Logcat:

```
08-23 15:29:25.735: D/AbsListView(25714): Get MotionRecognitionManager
08-23 15:29:25.745: D/AbsListView(25714): onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 4
08-23 15:29:25.745: D/AbsListView(25714): unregisterIRListener() is called 
08-23 15:29:25.745: D/AbsListView(25714): onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 0
08-23 15:29:25.745: D/AbsListView(25714): unregisterIRListener() is called 
08-23 15:29:25.775: D/AndroidRuntime(25714): Shutting down VM
08-23 15:29:25.775: W/dalvikvm(25714): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41ca7ac8)
08-23 15:29:25.775: E/AndroidRuntime(25714): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-23 15:29:25.775: E/AndroidRuntime(25714): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView
08-23 15:29:25.775: E/AndroidRuntime(25714):    at android.widget.AdapterView.addView(AdapterView.java:480)
08-23 15:29:25.775: E/AndroidRuntime(25714):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:503)
08-23 15:29:25.775: E/AndroidRuntime(25714):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
08-23 15:29:25.775: E/AndroidRuntime(25714):    at com.examples.flist.Adapter.getView(FlActivity.java:55)
08-23 15:29:25.775: E/AndroidRuntime(25714):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2619)
08-23 15:29:25.775: E/AndroidRuntime(25714):    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1253)
08-23 15:29:25.775: E/AndroidRuntime(25714):    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1165)
08-23 15:29:25.775: E/AndroidRuntime(25714):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16142)
08-23 15:29:25.775: E/AndroidRuntime(25714):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:666)
08-23 15:29:25.775: E/AndroidRuntime(25714):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:477)
08-23 15:29:25.775: E/AndroidRuntime(25714):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16142)
08-23 15:29:25.775: E/AndroidRuntime(25714):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4927)
08-23 15:29:25.775: E/AndroidRuntime(25714):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
08-23 15:29:25.775: E/AndroidRuntime(25714):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16142)
08-23 15:29:25.775: E/AndroidRuntime(25714):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:847)
08-23 15:29:25.775: E/AndroidRuntime(25714):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
08-23 15:29:25.775: E/AndroidRuntime(25714):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16142)
08-23 15:29:25.775: E/AndroidRuntime(25714):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4927)
08-23 15:29:25.775: E/AndroidRuntime(25714):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
08-23 15:29:25.775: E/AndroidRuntime(25714):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2475)
08-23 15:29:25.775: E/AndroidRuntime(25714):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16142)
08-23 15:29:25.775: E/AndroidRuntime(25714):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2167)
08-23 15:29:25.775: E/AndroidRuntime(25714):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1315)
08-23 15:29:25.775: E/AndroidRuntime(25714):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1526)
08-23 15:29:25.775: E/AndroidRuntime(25714):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1212)
08-23 15:29:25.775: E/AndroidRuntime(25714):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4981)
08-23 15:29:25.775: E/AndroidRuntime(25714):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:791)
08-23 15:29:25.775: E/AndroidRuntime(25714):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:591)
08-23 15:29:25.775: E/AndroidRuntime(25714):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:561)
08-23 15:29:25.775: E/AndroidRuntime(25714):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:777)
08-23 15:29:25.775: E/AndroidRuntime(25714):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
08-23 15:29:25.775: E/AndroidRuntime(25714):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-23 15:29:25.775: E/AndroidRuntime(25714):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-23 15:29:25.775: E/AndroidRuntime(25714):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5306)
08-23 15:29:25.775: E/AndroidRuntime(25714):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-23 15:29:25.775: E/AndroidRuntime(25714):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-23 15:29:25.775: E/AndroidRuntime(25714):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
08-23 15:29:25.775: E/AndroidRuntime(25714):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
08-23 15:29:25.775: E/AndroidRuntime(25714):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-23 15:29:35.065: I/Process(25714): Sending signal. PID: 25714 SIG: 9
```

java

```
package com.examples.flist;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class FlActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fl);


    ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
 int[] imgs ={R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.circle, R.drawable.why,         R.drawable.greenlogo}; 
String[] titles = {"First", "Second", "Third","Fourth"};


Adapter adapter = new Adapter(this, titles, imgs);
list.setAdapter(adapter);
}



}

class Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
    Context context;
    int[] imgs;
    String[] titles;
public Adapter(Context c, String[] titles, int[]imgs) {
    super(c, R.layout.extra, R.id.textView1, titles);

    this.context=c;//potential error
    this.imgs=imgs;//potential error
    //this.titles=titles;//potential error


}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater linf = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View row = linf.inflate(R.layout.extra, parent, true);
      ImageView img = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
      TextView txt1 = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
     // TextView txt2 = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    img.setImageResource(imgs[position]);
    txt1.setText(titles[position]);

    return row;
}
}
```

Comment: remove the View row and just replace with convertView or else assign convertview to row. And please assign this.titles ==tites

Answer (score 1):

Tell your adapter to not connect the views to your ListView:

```
linf.inflate(R.layout.extra, parent, false);
```

That way the `parent` is only used as a source for `LayoutParams` and the newly inflated views are not attached to the parent.

And also uncomment title set in your adapter's constructor:

```
this.titles=titles;
```

Sidenote: other **optimizations** might include:

- Re-using the `convertView`s
- Instantiating the `LayoutInflater` before `getView`
- Find views only when inflating and save them for further use